# Error when compiling PostgreSQL on Debian

Tags: linux, postgresql, debian

I'm compiling and installing postgresql on debian, but have some error:

```
In file included from pg_dump.c:60:0:
pg_backup_archiver.h:44:18: fatal error: zlib.h: No such file or directory
#include <zlib.h>
              ^
```

so I want to install zlib1g-dev , however, It reports :

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
zlib1g-dev{b} 
0 packages upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 64 not upgraded.
Need to get 192 kB of archives. After unpacking 446 kB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 zlib1g-dev : Depends: zlib1g (= 1:1.2.3.4.dfsg-3) but 1:1.2.8.dfsg-1 is installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

 Keep the following packages at their current version:
1) zlib1g-dev [Not Installed]                         
 Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] y
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 64 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

what should I do? thanks.

Comment: This is off topic for Stack Overflow and I've close-voted it. You probably want serverfault.com or superuser.com . Anyway, it looks like you have some package version pins in place, or a repository that provides a different zlib without a matching devel package. Try `apt-get install zlib1g zlib1g-dev`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since `postgresql` is already part of debian, why not just use the pre-packaged binary?

if this doesn't fit the bill (for whatever reasons), you can still benefit from the debian packaging effort by installing everything needed to build the debian packages (even if you want to build a psql package that is newer than the one in Debian or has other features, the build will be somehow similar):

```
# apt-get build-dep postgresql-9.3
```

and in any case you should make sure that your apt-database is uptodate, so you probably need to run

```
# apt-get update
```

before any other step.